# Subset of a list from an element

Tags: f#

I need to get the subset of a list from the first occurrence of an element in F#. I have implemented this using a simple recursive routine as follows:

```
// Returns a subset of a list from the first occurrence of a given item
// e.g. ignoreUpTo "B" ["A";"B";"C";"D"] yields ["C"; "D"]

let rec ignoreUpTo item l  = 
  match l with
  | hd::tl -> if hd = item then tl else ignoreUpTo item tl 
  | _ -> []
```

This works for my needs, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this using the existing List functions in the F# language.

Comment: What are you planning on returning if the list does not contain the element; an empty list?   Or should the function be returning a list wrapped in an option?

Comment: In my case the empty list is fine, as that is what I explicitly check for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using F# 4, there's now a `List.skipWhile` function; before F# 4, the `skipWhile` function was only available on `seq`s. So you could write:

```
let ignoreUpTo item l =
  l
  |> List.skipWhile ((<>) item)
  |> List.skip 1  // Because otherwise you'll get ["B"; "C"; "D"]
```

If you're using F# 3.1 or earlier, you'll need to turn your list into a `seq` first:

```
let ignoreUpTo item l =
  l
  |> List.toSeq
  |> Seq.skipWhile ((<>) item)
  |> Seq.skip 1  // Because otherwise you'll get ["B"; "C"; "D"]
  |> Seq.toList  // Optional, if you can get by with a seq instead of a list
```

Comment: Do note that I just wrote these and haven't tested them yet. In particular, I don't know what `List.skip 1` does when passed an empty list. The `match` suggestion that @hvester posted in his solution might be a good thing to try.

Comment: Oops, I wrote `takeWhile` instead of `skipWhile` by accident. And the two people who upvoted my incorrect solution before I corrected it didn't notice... tsk, tsk. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it using `List.skipWhile`. I assume that you want to return empty list if none of the elements of the list l equal item.

```
let ignoreUpTo item l =
    match List.skipWhile ((<>) item) l with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> xs
```